# pathping shows PC hop twice with 100% packet loss

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

[image: The issue]

The `pathping` to 185.60.112.157 (game server) shows my PC hop twice, the second time with 100% packet loss back from the router. 
Is this an issue? Since "Lost/Sent" after this hop are all 100% packet loss.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with pathping, but If you use an alternative product like tracert/traceroute or mtr does it show the same results? If so, I would suspect your network setup is incorrect and there is loop from the public side to the private side somewhere (maybe). Is this OS you are testing from a physical or VM environment?

Comment: Also, seeing more of the output might be beneficial here.

Comment: What happens if you try another server, like Google's Public DNS: ```pathping 8.8.8.8```?

Comment: This is from my personal PC at home. After the the line shown in the picture all further pings show 100/100 packet loss. Pinging Google's Public DNS is the same until the last hop which succeeds and arrives at my ISP with 16 ms and 0 packet loss

Comment: You need to tell us how your networking is configured on your machine because this is due to your on-device TCP/IP configuration.

Comment: I didn't change any settings lately - I have Cloudflare's DNS and a static address configured. Switching to obtaining IP automatically doesn't change the result. I'm connected directly to my router physically. If anything I think this might be somehow related to the windows 10 update since nothing else has changed

Answer (score 1):

Packet tracing uses ICMP to reach each hop on the route to your intended destination.

Seeing it timing out on every hop after your router just means your router is blocking outgoing ICMP (pings) for some reason.

It's neither 'good' nor 'bad', but it can be annoying for testing things, such as you've found here.

Comment: Did you look at the picture? That isn't what the OP is saying here... He is saying in a ping it showed hop 1 is 192.168.1.1 (his router) than it shows the PC he is using as hop 2, rather than showing the ISP's next next router as hop 2.

Comment: @acejavelin actually, it shows 0.0.0.0 as the IP, which happens (by chance) to resolve to localhost, and return his hostname.

Comment: Why would it come back to my PC though? Is that the behavior of `pathping` when ICMP is blocked?

Comment: I don't think it is, I think it's being blocked, and pingpath incorrectly sets the next hop to be 0.0.0.0 which then is resolved to point at your PC. Try using tracert instead, in a command prompt. `tracert 185.60.112.157`

Comment: tracert also shows this second hop back to my PC (0.0.0.0) after that it makes hop 3-4, reaching 5 only once, but everything after that is timed out (6-30).

Comment: Your PC isn't 0.0.0.0 though, nothing has that IP, it simply means 'all the IP's on the local machine', which if I ran it, would return my machines hostname. It's not actually going back to your PC from the router at all.